# Polymer 1.x: Styling disabled paper-input

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, jsbin, polymer-1.x

I want to format a `<paper-input disabled ...` element to appear NOT `disabled` (i.e., not have the text lightened out).

Below in my code ([and in this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/giguwoyoha/1/edit?html,output)) I show what I have tried so far.

How can I accomplish this? (Please provide a working demo. [Ideally, a clone of the subject jsBin](http://jsbin.com/giguwoyoha/1/edit?html,output).)

http://jsbin.com/giguwoyoha/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    /* Here is what I have tried so far */
    paper-input[disabled] {
      --paper-input: {
        color: black;
      }
    }
    paper-input {
      --paper-input-disabled: {
        color: black;
      }
    }
    paper-input {
      --paper-input-container-disabled: {
        color: black;
      }
    }
    paper-input[disabled] {
      color: black;
    }
    *[disabled] {
      color: black;
    }
  </style>

  <paper-input value="This is enabled text. I want to format the below to look like this."></paper-input>
  <paper-input value="This is disabled text. I want to format this to look like the above."
    disabled></paper-input>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
:host paper-input[disabled] {
  --paper-input-container-input-color: red;
  --paper-input-container-disabled: {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample on how you can apply mixins properly.

```
<style>
    :host {
      --paper-input-container-disabled: {
        color: pink;
        background: red;
        border: 5px dashed orange;
      };
    }
    paper-input {
      @apply(--paper-input-container-disabled);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: [Here is a demo of your answer](http://jsbin.com/bidebovofi/1/edit?html,output). It seems to style everything *except* for what I need... the text color. +1 because it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the convenience of future users, [here is a jsBin demo of the accepted answer](http://jsbin.com/mexirubida/1/edit?html,output).

And here is the full code:

http://jsbin.com/mexirubida/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
<style>
  :host paper-input[disabled] {
    --paper-input-container-input-color: red;
    --paper-input-container-disabled: {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
</style>
  <paper-input value="This is enabled text. I want to format the below to look like this."></paper-input>
  <paper-input value="This is disabled text. I want to format this to look like the above."
    disabled></paper-input>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

### Edit

The above worked in the jsBin demo. However, when trying to add it to my custom element, I had to modify the code as follows:

```
:host {
  paper-input[disabled] {
    --paper-input-container-input-color: red;
    --paper-input-container-disabled: {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```